# Corrupted boot partition

Tags: boot, mount, windows-10

I have Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Recently, I was trying to change a partition size on Ubuntu, but I failed. Then, just Windows was booting up.

To fix this, I created a bootable USB containing Ubuntu 17.04, and booted Ubuntu live. I don't know why, but unfortunately, after mounting `/dev/sda1` partition on `/mnt`, I removed the whole files in `/mnt` and rebooted.

Now, Windows doesn't boot too and I can work with Ubuntu live only. By mounting `/dev/sda1` on `/mnt`, I see there's no files and even directories in it. Making it simple, I have a corrupted `/dev/sda1`, which is empty.

How can I recover those files? Where to find them?

**EDIT:** On Ubuntu live, the full output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.3 GiB, 1427259392 bytes, 2787616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 349F53F1-D106-47B9-B4CD-37503947378E

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   2050047   2048000  1000M EFI System
/dev/sda2    2050048   2082815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3    2082816 388620383 386537568 184.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  492595200 493567999    972800   475M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  616450048 793219071 176769024  84.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  493568000 501381119   7813120   3.7G Linux swap
/dev/sda7  793219072 915331071 122112000  58.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  915331072 976771071  61440000  29.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  501381120 616450047 115068928  54.9G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7746879488 bytes, 15130624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00a590a4

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 15130623 15128576  7.2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you edit your question with the output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: I can give you a way to recover files from your Ubuntu (using an USB drive), but not for Windows, you will need after to reinstall this Ubuntu (and not with a 17.04, which is EOL)

Comment: Have you even try to remount your `/dev/sda1` partition ?

Comment: @damadam How to remount it?

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` or `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /opt` if the 1rst doesn't work

Comment: @damadam Yes, I mentioned in my question that I've tried it; but afterwards, there is no files and directories in /mnt.

Comment: @damadam Recovering files from my Ubuntu is not what I'm trying to perform, but I will appreciate if you help me. To be noted, I cannot mount my Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80376/discussion-between-damadam-and-machitgarha).

Comment: Your 17.04 is obsolete, use 18.04. Often easier to use Boot-Repair's advanced options and do full install of grub and check add newest kernel. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair